# Reload required module with Karma, Jasmine and karma-browserify

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, browserify, karma-jasmine

I'm working on a fairly big project and we used to use [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) for our unit tests. We decided to migrate towards [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html) + [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) because [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/), despite having some pros, was too slow for our needs and was sometimes crashing our continuous integration server, being more demanding in ressources than its counterparts.

The big advantage of [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) was that it was recreating an isolated environment for each test. It was possible to require a module in the `beforeEach` hook and then the code of the module was ran once again. Another advantage was the automatic mocking of all modules. With [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html) and [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/), you sometimes need to track down side effects to minimize undesired behaviours.

As for [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html) and [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/), it is way faster in comparison and the files watching feature allows us to do efficient TDD AND the other dev teams are happy we are not crashing our CI server anymore.

Back to my issue...

I'd like to know if it is possible to "clear `require` cache" before each test is ran. I know how [browserify](http://browserify.org/) works and how `require`s are done, but I'd be glad to know how some of you succeeded getting around this problem. The way it actually works, a new test could break an older test because it modifies the environment, which is really bad.

I tried [rewireify](https://github.com/i-like-robots/rewireify/issues/12), but it doesn't seem to play well with [watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify) (which is used by [karma-browserify](https://github.com/xdissent/karma-browserify)) and modified modules aren't reloaded properly since all rewireify'ed modules have a different reference in memory, and that prevents us to use `autoWatch` and to proper TDD.

Comment: Found anything yet on this Felix?

Comment: Nothing satisfying... I just implemented an init function to manually reinit my modules..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is a webstorm bug
[here you can see it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12496).

There I've found a solution which worked for me.

1. Modify this file (in osX):

`/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijRunner.js`

2. Modify refresh property to true like this:

`runWithConfig({
    port: serverPort,
    refresh: true, //<-- This
    urlRoot: urlRoot
  });`